# How can I create spaceships moving around automatic environment?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't want to control the spaceships and they are not enemies. I just want them to move around in space.
I have the spaceships models and the space station I want the spaceships to move around. The idea is that when the player will move in the space station around he will see in the windows some environment of moving spaceships around.

I don't want just to move the spaceships between waypoints but to create some environment. Not sure yet what should be the logic and how to do it.

This is the spaceship object. In default there is only mesh renderer component:

[image: Spaceship]

And the space station:

[image: Space station]

I didn't yet try anything. I'm not sure how to start to work on it. I didn't find any tutorials yet.

Comment: This is a bit too broad to help you. How should the spaceships move? What do you mean with _create some environment_?

Comment: Do you actually want speceships to move? Or you want to only display those from your spacecraft window?

Comment: why do not animate them?

Comment: @IanH. Environment I mean displaying that something is happening outside the space station like spaceships moving around not a war or fights just to give some life to the outside. Move I mean the space ships will move randomly around the space station area like the small spaceship are travelling like they are making some trip or just for fun. So if I will look at the window I will see some spaceships moving flying around randomly maybe in some cases I will see two or three spaceship moving together like friends making fun.

Comment: @IanH. But the main idea is to give some life to the outside. Like in space games when the player is looking up and see spaceships moving in the sky.  Or like in nature games when there are birds flying in the sky.

Comment: @PrachiJoshi Since for now I don't want to control the spaceships it can be the second part question you asked: "Or you want to only display those from your spacecraft window?"

Comment: @Lotan I thought about it too. But how do I animates for example 20-30 spaceships and create random movement animation around the space station area ? Seems not easy to create this animation mostly if I want that each time you will look at the window/s you will something else I mean the animation/movement of the spaceships should be randomly. Not something the same when you look each time again in the window/s

Comment: The main issue I have with imagining what you want to achieve is that movment in space is not _random_. In my eyes, it would be rather distracting to the player if the movement would be completely different each time. Or am I misunderstanding your idea?

Comment: @IanH. In second thought I think you right. Doing something once like one animation will be good enough. After all the player is not going to watch the window/s all the time. It's just to give some effect that there is some life/movement outside. So I guess I can leave the random part out. Just to make somehow something that will give some feeling that there is a life movements out side.

Comment: @DanielLip and if you want to add some "random" effect, you only need to make a couple of different animations, and fire them randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about boids.

https://www.google.de/search?q=boid+behaviour&rlz=1C1ASRM_enDE593DE593&oq=boid+beha&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5178j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

You could model the spaceships with these algorithms. This will result in a complete random behavior, but with interesting restrictions, such as don't come to near to the station, avoid other spaceship or don't get to far away from the Station.

Looks like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbUPfMXXQIY

This can be done very easily in Unity.